# Exclude "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator" from "metro-react-native-babel-preset"

Tags: plugins, jestjs, babeljs, metro-bundler, regenerator-runtime

I am using `metro-react-native-babel-preset`, but I need to exclude `@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator`. I tried all sort of things, but nothing works. I suspect that the issue is that `metro-react-native-babel-preset` requires the plugin directly, like this:

```js
///node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-preset/src/configs/main.js

          plugins: [
          ...defaultPluginsBeforeRegenerator,
          isHermes ? null : require("@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator"),
          ...defaultPluginsAfterRegenerator
        ].filter(Boolean)
```

Is there any way to disable this plugin but keep using the metro preset??

My current config looks like this:

```js
const babelOptions = {presets: [['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', {exclude: ['regenerator-transform']}]], 
module.exports = require('babel-jest').createTransformer(babelOptions);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in latest metro-preset it has been removed

https://github.com/facebook/metro/releases/tag/v0.70.0